# What can I do with the slow and over-designed gmail user interface on Lubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, email, gmail

In both Chrome and Firefox browsers, I have some problems with the current Standard View of Gmail user interface compared to the previous standard view:

1. Fonts are bigger than before. It drastically reduce the number of emails that can fit in a screen. I have to do more scroll up and down.
2. The automatic completion in search box does a little too much, and half of the time automatically complete and start searching without me being able to correct the search words.
3. almost every operation is slower than before.
4. ... (More than I can type at the moment)

Let me know if I haven't learn to  use the new interfaces in a proper way.
I just need a simple user interface, when all the basic features are present.
The basic HTML version is simple. One feature that it misses and I like is that automatic retreival of new emails.

I haven't used MUA, MTA, MDA, MRA, or email clients  on my Lubuntu 18.04. Will that be a good solution too? ( If yes, can I keep emails on the remote servers, and store as few as possible on local Lubuntu ?)

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure this is a specific Ubuntu / Lubuntu issue. Google likes to make things horrible on a regular basis, and since this is in your browsers, it is a Google problem.

That said, maybe try reducing the zoom in Gmail (Crtl -) until everything looks normal.

Comment: I am also considering what (L)Ubuntu's solutions are better than the webmail and what (L)Ubuntu users are using/liking, so I asked here.

Comment: Thunderbird comes with Ubuntu, and is still a pretty good email client. Works well with every email provider I have thrown at it.

Comment: Does it download lots of read and unread emails to local machine?

Comment: When you first set it up, it will download all the new unread mail. After that, it downloads all the new unread mail as it comes through, depending on how you have configured the settings (ex. every 10 minutes). If you get a lot of mail, and you don't delete things along the way, it can fill up your hard drive quickly. You can leave everything on the Gmail server in case you accidentally delete something on Thunderbird.

Comment: Is leaving everying on the gmail server the default action?

Comment: I feel you 100% with this, but there's nothing we can do about the annoyingness of the new Gmail interface from the OS. I'm voting to close this as a bug report because it's a problem only the Gmail devs can fix. But I'd retract my vote if you made it clearer you are looking for an alternative...?

Answer (score 1):

> Fonts are bigger than before. It drastically reduce the number of emails that can fit in a screen.

Click the gear-shaped settings icon ⚙️ on the upper-right side of the screen and select *Settings* -> *General* tab -> *Default text style* -> Click the dropdown triangle **T** ▾ and select a smaller font size.

Click the gear-shaped settings icon on the upper-right side of the screen and select *Settings* -> *Display density* -> *Compact* view.

> The automatic completion in search box does a little too much, and half of the time automatically complete and start searching without me being able to correct the search words.

Click the gear-shaped settings icon on the upper-right side of the screen and select *Settings* -> *General* tab -> *Smart Compose* -> *Writing suggestions off*.

> Almost every operation is slower than before.

Visit this Gmail Help webpage: [See Gmail in standard or basic HTML version](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/15049). When you're in Basic HTML view, you won't see some Gmail features, including Chat, Spell checker, Keyboard shortcuts, Adding or importing contacts, Custom "from" addresses and Rich formatting, but Gmail will work faster in Lubuntu.